# Jquery DataTable Row update

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the `DataTable` row.data API to update the row I am interested in and it works fine i.e the row gets updated. After the update the datatable gets sorted.

```
oTable.row(renewalTable.row('#' + data.Id)).data(data).draw();
```

My question is, I want the row to remain in the same position and not get sorted after the row update. How do I achieve this? How do I stop the sorting?

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the docs for the .draw() function.](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

It looks like that is your problem, remove the .draw() as that will result in a full re-order of the table.